# Generating unique IDs

Tags: java, database, jpa, primary-key

Lets consider that I have a simple bug tracking system hosted on 10 servers and there is a centralized database. I have to ensure that bug ID is unique at all times and of course ID should be meaningful.

Couple of alternatives that I can think of are

1. Use an ID generation strategy provided by ORM frameworks such JPA (may be a sequence generator strategy or more precisely a Table generation strategy can be adopted). However I see these strategies as an increased overload on database as we are asking it to generate an ID before we insert it into the table.
2. I can use UUID which provides an Unique ID but those are not meaningful. Those are just 128 bit numbers.

Can we come up with a strategy that lets us to create ID at the application level and pass it on to Database just to insert it. Point worth noticing is its a distributed environment where there are can be concurrent session yet the ID generated by the applications running in various servers should be Unique.

Apologies for writing an essay before I put in my question but just looking for best way to handle the requirement and clear off any myths that I have in the approaches I mentioned above :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'meaningful?' In what sense is a sequence more meaningful than a UUID?

Comment: Let the database do it. It's good at that. Doing it in a distributed application is essentially infeasible.

Comment: Why do you need to generate the id **before** you insert it into the database?

Comment: The table sequence allows for preallocation of blocks of numbers, reducing the database load.   As the database is the central location for all applications in a distributed environment, sequencing in the database is usually the least complex solution.

Comment: @TomG.. when I say meaningful, Ids should be easy to remember for Users. For example **bugcategory-bugNum** (defect-1234) is more easy to remember than an UUID number 067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00. With the help of ID generation strategies we can generate custom ids that are combination of text and numbers.